# React-admin framework, how to style the datagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I read the documentation and I can't seem to style the datagrid 100% freely... I can only change small things, or am I wrong? Let's say I want to use the datagrid features, but I want to leave 100% of the styling to my discretion, is that possible?

The code below was the little I managed to style, but it's not enough:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    backgroundColor: '#1C00ff00',
    borderBottom: 'none',
    fontFamily:'Noto Sans Mono'
  },
  headerCell: {
    backgroundColor: 'MistyRose',
    border:'none',
    boxShadow:"none"
  },
  row: {
    color: '#fff',
    border:'none',
    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box",
    boxShadow:"0px 0px 6px #000000",
    opacity:"0.7",
    borderRadius:"5px",
  },
  coluna1: {
    width: '10%'
  },
  coluna2: {
    width: '35%'
  },
  coluna3: {
    width: '35%'
  },
});
```

Here's the link to the documentation, if anyone wants to:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html

Comment: Okay, include the necessary details.